# Add class=active on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollto

I have a one page website with a fixed header and some sections.
I am using scrollTo and localScroll to jump to each section, but I have a problem to add `class=active` to `a href` on scroll.

I can add `class=active`on click, but I do not know how to do it on scroll and obviously remove it when switching from "old" to "new" section.

This is what I have done, when clicking:

```
$('#menu').find('a').click(selectNav);
function selectNav() {
    $(this).parents('ul:first').find('a').removeClass('active').end().end().addClass('active');
}
function trigger(data) {
    var el = $('#menu').find('a[href$="' + data.id + '"]').get(0);
        selectNav.call(el);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#homepage"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#connections"><span>Connections</span></a></li>
</ul>

<section id="homepage" class="main">
..........
</section>

<section id="connections" class="main">
..........
</section>
```

Any help, please?

Comment: please post your markup too

Comment: [MDN: window onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.fn.inView = function(){
    //Window Object
    var win = $(window);
    //Object to Check
    obj = $(this);
    //the top Scroll Position in the page
    var scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
    //the end of the visible area in the page, starting from the scroll position
    var visibleArea = win.scrollTop() + win.height();
    //the end of the object to check
    var objEndPos = (obj.offset().top + obj.outerHeight());
    return(visibleArea >= objEndPos && scrollPosition <= objEndPos ? true : false)
};


$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($("#homepage").inView()) {
        //#homepage active
    } else if($("#connections").inView()) {
        //#connections active
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correct, you want to add the class, then make the window scroll to a certain position, and then remove the class when the scrolling is done.

You could take a look at this question: [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

And then my suggestion would be apply the "Active" class on click, and then remove it again, once the animation is completed, using the callback function.

http://jsfiddle.net/uc7KF/

```
$("body").animate(
    {
        scrollTop:$("#connections").offset().top},0, function(){
        console.log("Done - Remove class")}
    }
)
```

This is the only solution I could come up with, that will remove the class AFTER the scrolling is completed.